# Update a value in a table which has a foreign which requires a join, what is the elegant solution (efficient)

Tags: sql

I have two tables X and Y:

- X has columns ID (primary key), Name
- Y has a foreign key to X referencing the ID column.

I can only get the Name value from an input as related to X.

I need to update Y a value in Y

I do not want to hit the database twice; that is : to get the ID value in X by matching the name value and return this to be used in the update of Y  via WHERE

How do I write this SQL query, is there a complex query I can write ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: wht u need to update show  sample data

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to update in single query is following

```
     UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1

FROM
    Y AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN X AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: @red8alice any issues with my answer you marked it and then unmarked ?

Comment: ,No sorry mistake, ticket it again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but:

```
update Y
set ...
where Y.X_ID in (select X.ID from X where X.Name = '...');
```

This would update those rows of `Y` whose `X_ID` references a row of `X` with a matching `Name` value.